# How is page.trendDescriptions = {}; work in the given piece of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got code from http://cektkp.com/twittermarquee/twitmarquee.js to use a twitter style ticker:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

   //<![CDATA[
        var page={};
        $(function() {new FrontPage().init()});
   //]]>  
</script>
```

I understand there is an anonymous javascript function which creates an instance of FrontPage class and init's it. And `var page={};` is an object literal, but is it correct to define it here as first line of the script tag?
I found this in a JS tutorial, `You should not use an object literal at the beginning of a statement. This will lead to an error or not behave as you expect, because the { will be interpreted as the beginning of a block.`

Also, in my javascript file I have the following code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.stocksTicker = {
        attach: function( context, settings ) {
            page.trendDescriptions = {};
            loadTrendDescriptions();
        }
}
.
.
.
var processSummizeInternal = function (B) {
    var J = page.trendDescriptions[page.query];
.
.
.
function loadTrendDescriptions() {
    $("#trends a").each(function () {
        var A = $(this);
        var C = A.parent().find("em");
        if (C.length) {
            var B = A.text();
            var D = C.text().replace(new RegExp(B.replace(/([^\w])/gi, "\\$1"), "gi"), "<strong>" + B + "</strong>");
            var E = A.attr("title").length ? A.attr("title") : A.attr("name");page.trendDescriptions[E] = [B, D]
        }
    })
}
```

I'm not able to understand how is js accessing this variable `page.`? There is no other reference of `page` anywhere else in any other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to define it here as first line of the script tag?
>
> > You should not use an object literal at the beginning of a statement. This will lead to an error or not behave as you expect, because the `{` will be interpreted as the beginning of a block.

This quotation does target constructs like

```
{init: function(){/* do something*/}}.init();
```

where really the statement begins with an object literal. Pretty odd? Yes, you would never use such code anyway. In your case,

> ```
> var page = {};
> ```

the object literal is inside the assignment statement. No problems here, it's totally fine.

---

> I'm not able to understand how is js accessing this variable `page.`?

Then it will automatically refer to a global variable. And you actually even *have* defined such one in your first snippet, and initialised it to an empty object. The external js you included then defined a `trendDescriptions` property on it and accessed it happily a few times.